# Retreving an image stored on SQl Server CE 3.1

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, image-manipulation, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a WinForm app for Windows Mobile 6.0 with C#, .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 and SqlServer CE 3.1.

I have this code that is not working:

```
using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        //read the signature from the database
        long imgSize = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
        image= new byte[imgSize];
        reader.GetBytes(0, 0, image, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I think there is a problem obtaining all data stored on the column containing bytes from the image.

When I do this:

```
bitmapImage = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(image));
```

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException.

But if I use a TableAdapter to obtain the image it works perfectly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(image)
bitmapImage = new Bitmap(ms);
// dont close the memorystream
```

**Update**

The problem lies with

```
reader.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, 0);
```

Clearly it needs to be more than 0 bytes in length (last parameter).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've changed that line of code to: reader.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, imgSize);
And, it works!!!

Comment: Cool, glad it was easy, sometimes these things just happen :)